# jquery click handler inside frame isn't working

Tags: jquery, click, frameset

I can't make the following code attach a click handler to the  elements on the "main" frame. This code is in the frameset definition.

```
<!-- #include file ="..\include\AuthenticationCheck.asp" --> 
<!-- #include file ="..\include\serverValidate.asp" --> 

<html>
<head>
<meta NAME="GENERATOR" Content="Microsoft Visual InterDev 1.0">
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Raider Writer Student Roll</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../include/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../include/js/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){//document ready

       $("#main").ready(function () { //The function below executes once the iframe has finished loading

                  $("#main .confirmLink").click(function(e) {
                    alert('hi');

                    });
                });


} );
</script>

</head>
<%
    course_id=request("course_Id")
    if ValidateNumber(course_id)=false then 
        err.raise 8,"Validation: <course_id> is Invalid","<course_id> is: " & course_id
    End if


%>
<%session("currentpage")="tracking"%>

<frameset rows="100,*" border="0">
  <frame name="banner" id="banner" scrolling="no" target="contents" src="rollbanner.asp?course_id=<%response.write(course_id)%>">
  <frameset cols="16%,*" border="5">
    <frame name="contents" id="contents" src="roll.asp?course_id=<%response.write(course_id)%>">



        <frame name="main" id="main" src="../action/helpread.asp?dm=trackingdocs">

  </frameset>
  <noframes>
  <body>
  <p>This page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support them.</p>

  </noframes>
</frameset>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery and frames - $(document).ready doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221192/jquery-and-frames-document-ready-doesnt-work)

Comment: I don't think this is about when the "ready" fires, as he's waiting for both here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using `#main` as the context?

```
$(".confirmLink","#main").click(function(e) {('hi');});
```

or changing 
`$("#main").ready(fn)` to `$("#main").load(fn)`

Comment: That won't change anything. The "context" is just syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 1):

You can't look inside the DOM of a `<frame>` that way. Try this:

```
$('#main').contents().find('.confirmLink').click(function() { ... });
```

Now, even that *might* have problems in some circumstances. If the page in the frame *also* imports jQuery, then you can do this:

```
$('#main').get(0).contentWindow.$('.confirmLink').click(function() { ... });
```

That would use the frame's own jQuery to set up the handler.

Answer (score 0):

Without doing a bunch of research I'd say it's probably a "document ready" issue.  You are waiting for the parent document, but not the frame document.  The parent document is considered "loaded" once all the elements for that page. Since frames are not technically part of the page, but rather a page unto themselves they are not considered.

If you have control of the page loaded into the frame a quick work around would be to encapsulate that jQuery call in a function and then call that function in the frame's page.

Comment: ... except he's doing the work in a "ready" handler on the frame.